# Draft enablement on a sap.fe.macros.Table in FPM scenario

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to activate the draft handling scenario in a metadata driven table in edit mode inside a Flexible Programming Mode Custom Page.

In the FPM Explorer I found an [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/fe/core/fpmExplorer/index.html#/controllerExtensions/customEditFlow) but it is leveraging the editflowApi only on a single table row (and in a separate form, not inline). I'd like to activate the draft in an inline edit scenario, i.e. on the whole table, but unfortunately the documentation is not helping me at all. I think that something similar is achieved in the Fiori Elements standard ObjectPage.
Is it possible to replicate the same behavior with building blocks and extensionApis?